# Typing an iterator in Typescript

Tags: typescript, iterator

I've got a function that takes a dictionary/object of arrays and adds an iterator to the object. On each `next()` call, the iterator returns an object with one element of each array (the goal is to have a unified interface between a dictionary of arrays and an array of dictionaries). I'd like to use the keys and values of the arrays to type the return type (`TReturn`).

```
const obj = { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [4, 5, 6], z: ["a", "b", "c"] };
const arr = [
  { x: 1, y: 4, z: "a" },
  { x: 2, y: 5, z: "b" },
  { x: 3, y: 6, z: "c" },
];

const DONE = { done: true, value: undefined };

const addLongIterator = (data: Record<string, any[]>) => {
  Object.defineProperty(data, Symbol.iterator, {
    value: function () {
      const keys = Object.keys(data);
      let i = 0;
      return {
        next() {
          if (!(i < data[keys[0]].length)) return DONE;
          const value = {} as Record<string, any>;
          for (const key of keys) value[key] = data[key][i];
          i++;
          return { done: false, value };
        },
      };
    },
  });
  // this is the line I want to type vv
  return data as typeof data & { [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<any, any, any> };
};

const objIt = addLongIterator(obj);

// Same iteration:
for (const x of objIt) console.log(x); // { x : 1, y : 4, c: "a" }, ...
for (const x of arr) console.log(x); // { x : 1, y : 4, c: "a" }, ...
```

Do you know how to correctly type this? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just make an array rather then making iterator?

Answer (score 1):

You want `T` to be `IterableIterator<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K][number] }>`

```
const obj = { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [4, 5, 6], z: ["a", "b", "c"] };

function addIter<T extends Record<string, any[]>>(o: T) {
    function* iter(this: T) {
        let firstKey = Object.keys(this)[0] as keyof T;
        for (let i = 0; i < this[firstKey].length; i++) {
            yield Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(this).map(([k, v]) => [k, v[i]])
            );
        }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(o, Symbol.iterator, {
        value: iter,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
    })
    return o as T & IterableIterator<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K][number] }>
}

for (const x of addIter(obj)) console.log(x);
```